# is it possible to refund a transaction using paypal

Tags: php, paypal

In my website ,i need to refund a successful transaction. I have stored the transaction ID in my database.when clicking on the particular transaction ID ,i wish to go to the detail page of the transaction .Is it possible with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) API to pull details about a particular transaction and generate/display a nice detail page that includes a refund link/button of some sort.

Then you can use the [RefundTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) API to actually process the refund when that gets triggered.

If you're working with PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It will make these API calls very simple for you, and you could have it done within a matter of minutes.